# Is an SRID unique?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, srid

I wonder why the Authority and the SRID are often both used together to refer to a CRS, like in `EPSG:4326`.
Isn't the SRID unique?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system#Identifier) says it is a "unique value", but also that spatial vendors may have created "[...] their own SRID implementation or refer to those of an authority, [...]". What does that mean, creating an own SRID implementation?

After browsing through [spatialreference.org](https://spatialreference.org/ref/) it seems that there are no duplicate SRIDs for different authorities.

If this is true and SRIDs are truly unique, why the OGC `spatial_ref_sys` metadata table (see Wikipedia link above; you may find this table in databases like PostGIS) is defined with both, an `SRID` column as well as an `AUTH_SRID` column? In a default PostGIS setup (6184 EPSG and 2315 ESRI entries), both columns always have the same value per row. If I wanted to add an user-defined entry, why would I want to choose different values for those columns?

Or if I were an authority, what could be the rationale for a decision that would cause me to define an SRID that has already been defined by another authority?

Comment: Obviously, the same *authority* doesn't assign the same *identifier* (number) to different entities. But different authorities may have, historically. EPSG is just one of them, and the most common. Across all combinations, implementations use *SRID* identifiers that are unique across their library, wh *proj4* being the most commonly used in FOSS GIS applications.

Comment: The most problematic case would be the new srid. Until the autorities recognize it, you have to create a temporary SRID, so the definitive SRID can be different in the end, and you can have overlaps if someone use the same number at the same time. An example is the SRID 3857 that was the 900913 when created by google (it's google in leetspeak). Google decided its number so people can use it until it was officially added by EPSG, so there potentially was other people creating a projection at the same time with the same number without knowing.

Comment: The story above is not true, 900913 was not invented by Google but by an open source developer Christopher Schmidt https://crschmidt.net/blog/archives/243/google-projection-900913/.

Comment: The story is doubly not true, 900913 was never added to the EPSG registry

Comment: @geozelot not that obvious, EPSG does assign the same identifier to different entities

Comment: @nmtoken ya, those are (I)OGP specific area definitions for their extraction field delineations - added to the EPSG database because, well, they can, I guess - having nothing in common with CRS definitions. So, with this in mind and while *entities* may be a misleading term, it stays true to the fact that for CRS, and within the same authority, identifiers are unique.

Comment: @geozelot, the EPSG codes for datum, extent etc are used in definitions of a CRS, just look at the WKT for EPSG:4326 (CRS) ~ https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/4326.  I've seen parsers fail to work out the projection of a GeoTIFF because there has been an assumption that all EPGS codes in a WKT refer to CRS, rather than to components of a CRS. for example `java.lang.Exception: The following projections (epsgs) are not supported: 9001 at org.apache.jsp.geopack2_jsp._jspService(geopack2_jsp.java:669)` where the 9001 in question is a reference to the SI base unit for length, and not the IGS97 CRS.

Comment: @nmtoken don't mistake my comments as an excuse for the structure of the EPSG registry in particular. However, this is a mix-up of domains: one is a *CRS* (and this question is about SRIDs), the other a *unit of measure* - which is clearly distinct even within the EPSG database (`urn:ogc:def:crs` vs `urn:ogc:def:uom`), and wthin the *CRS* domain, identifiers are unique - and lastly, if parsers are capable to distinguish lies in the domain of the developers...

Answer (score 2):

`EPSG:4326` isn't unique even for EPSG codes.

Within the EPSG Geodetic parameter dataset, `EPSG:4326` can either refer to a **CRS** or an **Extent**.

- [EPSG:4326 (extent)](https://epsg.org/extent_4326/USA-Wisconsin-Douglas.html)
- [EPSG:4326 (CRS)](https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html)

For uniqueness you need the full identifier (URI)

Codes [2315](https://epsg.org/search/by-name/?query=2315&displayTabs=all) and [6184](https://epsg.org/search/by-name/?query=6184&displayTabs=all) are also both used by EPSG to define CRS inter al.